# Class 'App\Http\Middleware\DB' not found when using Middleware in Laravel 5

Tags: php, database, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

So I want to check whether the database is connected in laravel 5.I used Middlewares for this.

Middleware code

Middleware.php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

```
use Closure;


class MyMiddleware {

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

            if(DB::connection()->getDatabaseName())
            {
                    echo "conncted sucessfully to database ".DB::connection()->getDatabaseName();
            }else{
                    die("Couldn't connect");
            }



        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

added it to kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'error' => 'App\Http\Middleware\MyMiddleware',
    'auth' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate',
    'auth.basic' => 'Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth',
    'guest' => 'App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated',
];
```

and I want to check if there is an error in a particular route

```
Route::get('/wow', ['middleware' => 'error', function () {
    //
}]);
```

Every thing works fine for the middleware but no classes or laravel core functions like check db is working.How do I solve it?

This is the error laravel shows

```
FatalErrorException in MyMiddleware.php line 18:
Class 'App\Http\Middleware\DB' not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're working in namespace `App\Http\Middleware`. So it searches for DB in that namespace unless you specify otherwise.

Either set

```
use DB;
```

Or use the DB as

```
\DB::connection()->...
```

More info on namespaces: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Comment: where do I put use DB;?

Comment: Above your class defenition, in your case above or below `use Closure`.