# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DB' not found in Laravel 5 Controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a problem using the laravel 5 query builder for an Employee management system. Here is my EmployeesController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Employee;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class EmployeesController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        // $employees = Employee::all();
        // return view('employees.index', compact('employees'));

        $employees = DB::table('employees')->get();

        return view('employees.index', compact('employees'));
    }

}
```

When i use the commented out code, the view works and i can see my employee list

```
$employees = Employee::all();
return view('employees.index', compact('employees'));
```

I saw an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30211608/class-app-http-middleware-db-not-found-when-using-middleware-in-laravel-5) here, and i did as suggested but no luck. I added use DB; after the namespace declaration and also tried the code with

```
$employees = \DB::table('employees')->get();
```

but it throws another error which says Call to a member function count() on a non-object on line 6.
I even copied the DB.php file from C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel5project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades to the App folder (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel5project\app) but still  no luck. 
I've also tried to explicitly give it the namespace

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB
```

Here is the view

```
@extends('layouts.default')
@section('PageTitle', 'Employee List')
@section('content')

@if ( !$employees->count() )
    There are no Employees!
@else    

<table id="tblEmployee" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach( $employees as $employee )
        <tr>             
            <td>{{$employee->Name}}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach

    </tbody>
</table>

@endif
@endsection
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Where are you trying to use `->count()`? I don't see it in your code. Also, if you try to call `->count()` on a `null` object, you'll get that error. ALSO, using `\DB` will get rid of the error in your title. That is a namespacing issue which is resolved by using the \. It's unfortunate that your encountered another error right afterwards, but they are somewhat unrelated.

Comment: Just included the view on the question

Comment: Well, you were right. It was the count function on the view that was giving me problems.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`DB` is not in your current namespace `App\Http\Controllers`. So you can either import it at the top

```
use DB;
```

or precede it with a backslash `\DB::table(...)`. This solves the class not found exception.

You are however not getting a Laravel Collection of Employee models but an array of database rows. Arrays are not objects that have a count() function which results in your final error.

Update: Laravel 5.3 will return a Collection object and not an array. So count() will work on that.

Answer (score 2):

The DB is not set in your Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use DB;
use App\Employee;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class EmployeesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        // $employees = Employee::all();
        // return view('employees.index', compact('employees'));
        $employees = DB::table('employees')->get();
        return view('employees.index', compact('employees'));
    }
}
```